# store data in two different table at the same time in database

Tags: reactjs, express, mern, next.js13, web-development-server

I am working on a site which data is already storing in a mysql database table but now I want to store the same data in another table also without making any kind of changes in backend(express). is it actually possible?

tell me the way how I can do it